# How can I use Jquery to make a css array?

Tags: html, jquery, css, arrays, css-animations

With Jquery I am breaking a paragraph apart to animate each word individually through an array.
Now I would like to us the same array to allocate a .css to the individual words.
How do I set this up in the script?

The script at the bottom breaks the paragraph  apart. Currently I have written out the list of css span classes. But I would love to make this dynamic as well, using the same jquery array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <title>Animated copy</title>

  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">


  <style id="INLINE_PEN_STYLESHEET_ID">
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat Medium";
  max-width: 60ch;
  text-align: center;
 transform: scale(0.94);
  animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
}
@keyframes scale {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}


<!--This list of CSS lines should be done with an array -->
span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: anim-lineUp 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0); 
    
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(7) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(8) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(9) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.9s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(10) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(11) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(12) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(13) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(14) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(15) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(16) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(17) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(18) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 1.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
       
.lineUp {
  animation: 1.5s anim-lineUp ease-out ;
}

@keyframes anim-lineUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
      
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script> 
    

</head>

<body>
  <h1>
  <p>It is a lawless time. Crime Syndicates compete for resources – food, medicine, and hyperfuel. On the shipbuilding planet of Corellia, the foul Lady Proxima forces runaways into a life of crime in exchange for shelter and protection. On these mean streets, a young man fights for survival, but yearns to fly among the stars…” </p>
</h1>

    
<!--Jquery to break words apart, that should also add a css rule to each word -->   
 <script>
var words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
var text = words.join( "</span> <span>" );
$( "p" ).first().html( "<span>" + text + "</span>" );
$( "span" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( this ).css("animation: 1.5s anim-lineUp ease-out forwards");
    
});
</script>

 
  

  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting one as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer). Doing that will acknowledge the answer and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) API fits better here. The below example also doesn't use jQuery, but the basic idea is the same...

```js
const animation = [
  {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  {
    opacity: 1,
  },
];
const options = {
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: 1,
  fill: "both",
};
const para = document.querySelector("p");
para.innerHTML = para.innerText
  .split(/\s+/g)
  .map((word) => `<span>${word}</span>`)
  .join(" ");
[...para.querySelectorAll("span")].forEach((span, index) => {
  span.animate(animation, { ...options, delay: index * 200 });
});
```

```html
<p>It is a lawless time. Crime Syndicates compete for resources – food, medicine, and hyperfuel. On the shipbuilding planet of Corellia, the foul Lady Proxima forces runaways into a life of crime in exchange for shelter and protection. On these mean streets,
  a young man fights for survival, but yearns to fly among the stars…”</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler example of how you can loop through your words array and add a class based on some criteria.

```js
const words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
let out = '';
$.each(words, function(idx, word){
  if (word.length < 5){
    out += `<span class="ani1">${word} </span>`;
  }else{
    out += `<span class="ani2">${word} </span>`;
  }
});
$('body').html(out);
```

```css
.ani1{color:red;}
.ani2{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>It was a dark and stormy night. The maid screamed. A door slammed. Suddenly a pirate ship appears on the horizon.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the CSS `animation-delay` dynamically.

First set the non-dynamic part of the animation styling to the `span` tag:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}
```

Then apply the *specific* CSS like this:

```
const $spans = words.map((word, i) =>
    $("<span>").text(word + "\xa0").css({ animationDelay: `${i/10}s` })
);
```

Snippet:

```js
const words = $( "p" ).first().text().match(/\S+/g);
const $spans = words.map((word, i) =>
    $("<span>").text(word + "\xa0").css({ animationDelay: `${i/10}s` })
);
$( "p" ).first().empty().append($spans);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat Medium";
  max-width: 60ch;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.94);
  animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
  font-size: smaller;
}
@keyframes scale {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
       
.lineUp {
  animation: 1.5s anim-lineUp ease-out ;
}

@keyframes anim-lineUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script> 
<h1>
  <p>It is a lawless time. Crime Syndicates compete for resources – food, medicine, and hyperfuel. On the shipbuilding planet of Corellia, the foul Lady Proxima forces runaways into a life of crime in exchange for shelter and protection. On these mean streets, a young man fights for survival, but yearns to fly among the stars…” </p>
</h1>
```